# How can I replace blank entries in a text table with 0 in Python?

Tags: python, text

I have tables which looks like this:

```
text = """
ID = 1234

Hello World              135,343    117,668    81,228
Another line of text    (30,632)              (48,063)
More text                  0         11,205       0    
Even more text                       1,447       681

ID = 18372

Another table                        35,323              38,302      909,381
Another line with text                 13                  15
More text here                                              7           0    
Even more text here                   7,011               1,447        681
"""
```

Is there a way to replace the "blank" entries in each table with 0?  I am trying to set delimiters between the entries, but using the following code can't deal with blank spots in the tables:

```
for line in text.splitlines():
    if 'ID' not in line:
        line1 = line.split()
        line = '|'.join((' '.join(line1[:-3]), '|'.join(line1[-3:])))
        print line
    else:
        print line
```

The output is:

```
ID = 1234
|
Hello World|135,343|117,668|81,228
Another line of|text|(30,632)|(48,063)
More text|0|11,205|0
Even more|text|1,447|681
|
ID = 18372
|
Another table|35,323|38,302|909,381
Another line with|text|13|15
More text|here|7|0
Even more text here|7,011|1,447|681
```

As you can see, the first problem shows up on the second line of the first table. The word 'text' is considered the first column.  Any way to fix this in Python to replace blank entries with 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function for finding columns in a bunch of lines. The second argument `pat` defines what a column is, and can be any regex.

```
import itertools as it
import re

def find_columns(lines, pat = r' '):
    '''
    Usage:
    widths = find_columns(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if not line: continue
        vals = [ line[widths[i]:widths[i+1]].strip() for i in range(len(widths)-1) ]
    '''
    widths = []
    maxlen = max(len(line) for line in lines)
    for line in lines:
        line = ''.join([line, ' '*(maxlen-len(line))])
        candidates = []
        for match in re.finditer(pat, line):
            candidates.extend(range(match.start(), match.end()+1))
        widths.append(set(candidates))
    widths = sorted(set.intersection(*widths))
    diffs = [widths[i+1]-widths[i] for i in range(len(widths)-1)]
    diffs = [None]+diffs
    widths = [w for d, w in zip(diffs, widths) if d != 1]
    if widths[0] != 0: widths = [0]+widths
    return widths

def report(text):
    for key, group in it.groupby(text.splitlines(), lambda line:line.startswith('ID')):
        lines = list(group)
        if key:
            print('\n'.join(lines))
        else:
            # r' (?![a-zA-Z])' defines a column to be any whitespace
            # not followed by alphabetic characters.
            widths = find_columns(lines, pat = r'\s(?![a-zA-Z])')
            for line in lines:
                if not line: continue
                vals = [ line[widths[i]:widths[i+1]] for i in range(len(widths)-1) ]
                vals = [v if v.strip() else v[1:]+'0' for v in vals]
                print('|'.join(vals))

text = """\
ID = 1234

Hello World              135,343    117,668    81,228
Another line of text    (30,632)              (48,063)
More text                  0         11,205       0    
Even more text                       1,447       681

ID = 18372

Another table                        35,323              38,302      909,381
Another line with text                 13                  15
More text here                                              7           0    
Even more text here                   7,011               1,447        681
"""

report(text)
```

yields

```
ID = 1234
Hello World         |     135,343|    117,668|    81,228
Another line of text|    (30,632)|          0|   (48,063)
More text           |       0    |     11,205|       0   
Even more text      |           0|     1,447 |      681
ID = 18372
Another table         |               35,323|              38,302|      909,381
Another line with text|                 13  |                15|0
More text here        |                    0|                 7  |         0   
Even more text here   |                7,011|               1,447|        681
```

Comment: This would work for the tables I have listed above.  However, the column positions can be different for every table and there are thousands of tables.  Can this be modified to avoid manually checking where columns begin for each table?

Comment: Columns for table 2 might not line up exactly under the columns of table 1 as they do in the example above.  There are only 3 columns for each table.